# Username and password in REST services

Tags: rest, authentication

When calling `GET /api/token` for login, where to put the username and password?

URL parameters or header?

I'm confused, because I read, the token should go into a header, when I request some other data later.

(I'm writing an API myself, I'm not using someone elses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login should be a `POST` request (you create a token). That way you could send the username and password in the body of the request.

```
POST /app/token HTTP/1.1

username=example&password=example
```

If credentials are correct, the request could return the token in the body.

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "token": "example"
}
```

You can then store this token on the client side (for example in local storage) and send it in the header for subsequent requests.

Comment: Ah, I had the idea that I only use `POST` when creating permanent resources on the server.

Comment: In this case the token is the resource. You can create it (login) and you can delete it (logout).